# Using Unison "-repeat watch" in FreeBSD (10.2) after installing from ports yields error

Tags: python, freebsd, ports, unison

After installing unison from /usr/ports/net/unison with X11 disabled via make config, running the command **unison -repeat watch /dir/mirror/1 /dir/mirror/2**

Yields the message:

> Fatal error: No file monitoring helper program found

From here I decided to try using pkg to install unison-nox11 and this yields the same error message.

I've also tried copying the fsmonitor.py file from unison-2.48.3.tar.gz to /usr/bin/unison-fsmonitor and I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Unexpected response 'Usage: unison-fsmonitor [options] root [path] [path]...' from the filesystem watcher (expected VERSION)

Running the command **unison-fsmonitor version** shows the message

> unsupported platform freebsd10

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the message is pretty clear: `unison-fsmonitor` can't be run on freebsd10 because it's not supported, so you can't use Unison with the `-repeat` option.

Since it's just written in Python, though, I don't see why it shouldn't be supported. Maybe message the developer.